# EXC_BAD_ACCESS, simple calculator, Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access

Alright everyone, I've been working on a simple calculator tutorial for iOS as several friends of mine want me to teach them some rudimentary concepts. I think I've spent too much time doing fine-tuning on apps I've already written because when I wrote this code, it was plagued with errors.

I'll post the code; explanation of how it works will come after.

```
#import "_23ViewController.h"

@interface _23ViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray* stack;
    NSMutableString *stringA;
    NSMutableString *stringB;
    NSMutableString *operation;
    NSUInteger *aorb;
}

@end

@implementation _23ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   [stack addObject: stringA];
   [stack addObject: stringB];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
   // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)zero:(id)sender
{
   [[stack objectAtIndex:*(aorb)] stringByAppendingString:@"0"];
}

- (IBAction)one:(id)sender
{
   [[stack objectAtIndex:*(aorb)] stringByAppendingString:@"1"];
}

- (IBAction)two:(id)sender
{
   [[stack objectAtIndex:*(aorb)] stringByAppendingString:@"2"];
}

- (IBAction)three:(id)sender
{
   [[stack objectAtIndex:*(aorb)] stringByAppendingString:@"3"];
}

- (IBAction)four:(id)sender
{
   [[stack objectAtIndex:*(aorb)] stringByAppendingString:@"4"];
}

- (IBAction)five:(id)sender
{
   [[stack objectAtIndex:*(aorb)] stringByAppendingString:@"5"];
}

- (IBAction)six:(id)sender
{
   [[stack objectAtIndex:*(aorb)] stringByAppendingString:@"6"];
}

- (IBAction)seven:(id)sender
{
   [[stack objectAtIndex:*(aorb)] stringByAppendingString:@"7"];
}

- (IBAction)eight:(id)sender
{
   [[stack objectAtIndex:*(aorb)] stringByAppendingString:@"8"];
}

- (IBAction)nine:(id)sender
{
   [[stack objectAtIndex:*(aorb)] stringByAppendingString:@"9"];
}

- (IBAction)decimal:(id)sender
{
   [[stack objectAtIndex:*(aorb)] stringByAppendingString:@"."];
}

- (IBAction)equals:(id)sender
{
   float a = [[stack objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
   float b = [[stack objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];
   float answer;

   if ([operation isEqualToString:@"addition"])
   {
       answer = a + b;
   }
   if ([operation isEqualToString:@"subtraction"])
   {  
       answer = a - b;
   }
   if ([operation isEqualToString:@"multiplication"])
   {
       answer = a * b;
   }
   else
   {
       answer = a / b;
   }
   self.disp.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",answer];
}

- (IBAction)clear:(id)sender
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        [stack insertObject:@"0" atIndex:i];
    }
}

- (IBAction)plus:(id)sender
{
    aorb++;
    [operation setString: @"addition"];
}

- (IBAction)minus:(id)sender
{
    aorb++;
    [operation setString: @"subtraction"];
}

- (IBAction)div:(id)sender
{
    aorb++;
    [operation setString: @"division"];
}

- (IBAction)mult:(id)sender
{
    aorb++;
    [operation setString: @"multiplication"];
}

@end
```

Now, ideally what this code is supposed to do is upon loading the view, add `stringA` and `stringB` to the array called `stack`. Every number that is pressed should append to the string located at the array index specified by the NSUInteger `aorb`. Initially this is zero, but when an operation button is pressed, it increments, and the `operation` NSString is set to the specific operation. Once the NSUInteger is incremented, the number keys append to `stringB` instead of `stringA`.The `equals IBAction` takes that into account and spins the result accordingly.

Problem is, whenever I simulate this, I get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS error, code 2, address 0x0` on whichever key I press first, specifically on the line that ideally performs. I had to debug a `SIGABRT` before, and nothing that helped that really works on this error. This is the first time I've thrown a memory exception like this, and so I'm really lost on what to do.

If this isn't enough detail/if you need more code (the `.h` file), let me know and I'll post it through. Thanks, everyone.

Comment: There's no reason to have a millionty-billionty `IBAction` methods: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/41761/how-can-i-condense-several-ibaction-methods-in-a-class-with-a-delegate

Comment: That works well enough, and is simple to understand. I'll work on implementing that into my next project.

Comment: It works particularly well in an instance like this where you have buttons that correspond to numbers.  Just set the tag on each numbered button to correspond to the number the button represents.

Comment: Yep. And it certainly does me more favors than me having to individually debug 17 or so `IBAction` instances. Any idea on the `NaN` difficulty I commented to your answer?

Comment: NSUInteger *aorb is a red flag. NSUInteger is not an object, it is just an integer. It is exceedingly unlikely that you wanted an NSUInteger*. You should also read the definition of "stringByAppendingString", because the way you are using it makes absolutely no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @gnasher729 Super, if you looked over the question you would've noticed that it's been solved by now - meaning, I realized that `appendString:` was the correct method for use. Also, if `NSUInteger` is just an unsigned integer, then there is no 'red flag' - either can be used. I used `NSUInteger` for the ease of interconversion, which I didn't end up needing. That is an example of changes I would make after I got past actual errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your `viewDidLoad`

```
[super viewDidLoad];

stack = [NSMutableArray array];
stringA = [NSMutableString string];
stringB = [NSMutableString string];

[stack addObject: stringA];
[stack addObject: stringB];
```

You also need to initialize `aorb` (and give it a better name).  It also probably doesn't need to be a pointer.

Change it to `NSUInteger aOrB;` and add `aOrB = 0` to `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Still throws the exception.

Comment: Check the edit, make sure you're also initializing the iVar you're using for the index.

Comment: The pointer character was Fix-It'd in. Preferentially I've always used the C `int` so I don't have much experience with `NSInteger/NSUInteger`.

Comment: NSInteger is a C `int` on 32-bit systems and a C `long long` on 64-bit systems.  NSUInteger is the same except unsigned.  What you have is a pointer to one of these variables, which would be like `unsigned int * aOrB` in C.

Comment: I made the changes, and it works. The only issue is that the UILabel disp reports `NaN` as a result. That being said, I'll mark your answer as the correct one, thanks.

Comment: Please see the link I left in the comment to the question for some help cleaning up your code.